# Is there a way to create a library of classes spread amongst numerous Swift files, without creating a framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to group a number of Swift files together into a library of shared code to use between several of our SDK projects? The caveat is we don't want these libraries' classes and functions to be exposed to our clients whom are embedding the binary frameworks of our SDKs

We are creating a suite of iOS SDK as a binary framework to ship to our customers. Between these frameworks, we have various modules of common code (backend abstraction module, etc). One way I tried to modularize these common code is to pack them into yet another framework. However this forces us to not only expose the public functions of these internal modules to our own SDKs, but also all the way to our customer's apps. This includes functions to access internal backend endpoints, which is a big nono.

The other approach attempted is to create Git submodules around a group of loose Swift files. The downside here is if this submodule have file additions or removal, the SDK project will need to manually reflect the file addition or removal.

Comment: So in a sense what you want is to create a framework that uses other frameworks privately. As in the application that would your your framework has no access to the frameworks that are being used by your framework. This might make sense in your case but it seems generally a bad idea. Imagine I create a framework that uses some framework like Alamofire and make that framework private. Now an application uses my Framework but would also like to use Alamofire. If it included another version of it the project would not be buildable as it would have conflicting types.

Comment: I would consider merging your frameworks. So create a new framework and paste all the code from your other frameworks into your framework and mark it as internal. Probably wrapping it into some internal class would be best (to mimic namespaces).

Comment: ...as for the other idea to have multiple files which share private code I simply don't see a way. How Swift access control is defined this should not be possible. I admit that I had a few situations as well where this would be helpful; it would be nice to have something like C++ friendship in Swift.

Comment: Matic you got my question exactly right. In the case where the client has Alamofire and our SDK has Alamofire, I think the right way is our SDK should include that as public. But it'd still be useful to be able to hide our own internal modules.

The copy/pasting entire classes solution is what we are using now, and we make it a bit more sharable by wrapping them in a git submodule. However each individual project needs to track if any files have been added or removed, and that's a pain.